# positioning a div element relative to an image

Tags: jquery

Can anyone please tell me how to do this, right now when i click an image in my website a menu opens up right under the image but when I resize the window the menu stays where were it popped out initially but the image moves, so how can i position this menu under the image without using window.resize or jquery resize events. This is the code i have right now

```
$('#div').css({
    "left": ($("#menu").offset().left + ($("#menu").width()/2)) + "px",
    "top": ($("#menu").offset().top + $("#menu").height()) + "px",
    "position":"absolute"
});
```

Comment: Today my mystical powers are not that good. So you will need to post a little bit more of what you have done.

Comment: Have you tried `position:relative` instead of `position:absolute`?

Comment: relative wont work because when i click on the image the menu should open below that image, which currently does but whats happening is when i resize the window, the gap increases between the image and menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a div with similar size as image size, mark their position as relative

```
style="position:relative;"
```

Place both image and div you mentioned above in newly created div.

Hope this will help you.